# How Power BI handles data filtering based on user access?

Tags: authentication, reporting-services, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

Can we add user restriction in SQL like SSRS report or do we need to do something else? 
We are using a master PBI account to embed the report feature.

**Access permission need to set on data level. Within any power BI report, user has to see the data which is allowed with some permission level. It has to be data filtering based on user permissions.**

Answer (score 1):

1. You create your gateway and make sure it's ready to go.
2. Use Power BI desktop to create your reports and data sets.
3. Publish your solution to Power BI service "online version" app workspace ( requires Power BI pro or premium license.
4. From Power BI service, create a new app and select which reports to include, from this wizard, it will ask you who can see this application and view it's content.
5. Publish the application and only allowed users will be able to use it.

You may need to read this article - [Create and publish Power BI apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-create-distribute-apps/)

Comment: It has to be data filtering based on user permissions

Comment: Look into 'Row Level Security' with Power BI